# Fail to set meta tags from Yii2 controller

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

In controller I have

```
$this->view = $this->getView();
...
$this->view->registerMetaTag(['name' => 'meta', 'content' => '...']);
$this->view->render();
```

In view `<?php $this->head() ?>` results in inserting assets only, with no metas:

```
<link href="/frontend/web/assets/a8c97299/toolbar.css" rel="stylesheet">
...
```

The rest of the page is rendered fine.

I've tried to figure out what happens in the framework during head insertion [here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/2.0.6/framework/web/View.php#L170). It seems that `$this->clear();` disables metas from being rendered. I've successfully logged

```
<meta name="meta" content="...">
<link href="/frontend/web/assets/a8c97299/toolbar.css" rel="stylesheet">
...
```

from there, and with commented `$this->clear();` metas are rendered in view as expected.

How this can be explained and fixed?

Answer (score 2):

You should do in your controller:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    \Yii::$app->view->registerMetaTag([
        'name' => 'description',
        'content' => 'Description of the page...'
    ]);
    return $this->render('index');
}
```

And in the layout file:

```
<head>
    <?php $this->head() ?>
</head>
```

Comment: Actually, I've had to store the view as controller property , `$this->view = $this->getView();` to have access to view properties, so I called render and registerMetaTag on this view object and believed that everything is fine.

Comment: Thanks, doing `\Yii::$app->view->registerMetaTag(...); return $this->view->render(...);` does the trick for me. But what is the explanation for that?

Comment: I saw from the documentation you can read more from here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-views.html